# Instantiation Overwriting Previous Instances (Backbone.js Models)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I seem to be having an issue with this little snippet. I've fiddled with it for quite some time and it keeps overwriting the global attributes of all previous instantiations when a global attribute of the same name is changed on the next instantiation of the same Model.

This effect of this issue is breaking a simple web navigation editor I'm building, in which each time a Collection is fetched, even though they are separate instantiations of the same Collection type, they overwrite any models on any other Collections because of the globals being overwritten.

Needless to say, I've been banging my head against the wall for three days now, and cannot figure it out nor find anything on Google related to this sort of issue.  Any help with this issue is greatly appreciated.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alexgurrola/ruv11nkn/

```
// Create Example Model
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    globals: {
        attributes: {},
        set: function (prop, value) {
            this.attributes[prop] = value;
        },
        get: function (prop) {
            return this.attributes[prop]
        },
        has: function (prop) {
            return _.has(this.attributes, prop);
        },
        iterate: function (prop) {
            if (!this.has(prop)) this.set(prop, 0);
            return ++this.attributes[prop];
        }
    },
    local: "Unknown"
});

// Create First Instance
var Instance = new Model();
Instance.local = "Instance";
Instance.globals.set("name", "Instance");

// Create Second Instance, which will Overwrite the First, Unintentionally
var Overwrite = new Model();
Overwrite.local = "Overwrite";
Overwrite.globals.set("name", "Overwrite");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `global` object is declared with the `Model` then the context is bound to that object and not to the instances you create later. It's basically acts like a static variable, so every instance will be referencing the same `attributes` object.

What you seem to want is to have each instance of the model have it's own `attributes` which you can do, for example, by setting it in an initialize function instead

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.globals = {
            attributes: {},
            set: function (prop, value) {
                this.attributes[prop] = value;
            },
            get: function (prop) {
                return this.attributes[prop]
            },
            has: function (prop) {
                return _.has(this.attributes, prop);
            },
            iterate: function (prop) {
                if (!this.has(prop)) this.set(prop, 0);
                return ++this.attributes[prop];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

That will ensure that each instance creates its own `globals` and that the context is bound correctly when `set` is called.

I'm a bit curious about why you're doing this, though. It seems like you're kind of reimplenting a model inside a model?

Comment: I am currently building a simple core in which it creates Relational Models based on the "Stratus.Models.Generic" Model and can Dynamically Relate them if the Model has previously been accessed or will be accessed in the future.  The other reason for the "globals" space is to allow data from the Collection, as it iterates, to be sent to the Underscore Template.  The (broken) code I'm referring to can be seen in the following url: http://js.sitetheory.io/2/0/stratus.html#section-51

Comment: @AlexGurrola I think they're doing it that way exactly because they want shared state. For regular state variables on an instance (especially when it's a model) it probably better to stick with plain Backbone [get](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get) and [set](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) basically just doing `Instance.set("name", "Instance");`-

Comment: That totally makes sense.  Thanks for your help!